# SMTP Recipient Refused Python

Tags: python, email, tkinter, one-time-password

I'm coding a password changer in Python, I'm currently working on the section that creates an OTP then emails it to the user.

It should function as:

Create Otp -> Display tkinter window -> input email -> send otp to email

But I'm getting this error when trying to send the email;

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 880, in sendmail
raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (555, b'5.5.2 Syntax error. m201sm173146wma.13 - gsmtp')}
```

The tkinter window is also not displaying beforehand to actually take an input.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import smtplib

def main():
    otp = create_otp()
    user_email = layout(otp)
    send_otp(otp, user_email)


def layout(output):

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x400')
    root.config(bg='#10416A')
    email_in = StringVar()
    email = Entry(root, textvariable=email_in, width=50)
    email.place(x=190, y=145)
    label_otp = Label(root, text="Enter email address:  ", background='#10416A', font=('arial', 15, "bold"), fg='white').place(x=18, y=150)
    user_email = email_in.get()
    enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")
    enter_button.pack()
    enter_button.config(bg='#10416A', command=send_otp(output, user_email))
    root.mainloop()
    return user_email


def create_otp():
    contents = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@$%^&*()-_=+[]{}:;?/>.<,0123456789"
    pw_length = 8
    output = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(contents))
        output = output + contents[next_index]

    return output


def send_otp(output, user_email):
    content = output
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypass')
    mail.sendmail('myemail@gmail.com', user_email, content)
    mail.close


main()
```

1st question: Why isn't the tkinter window showing up when I run the program?

2nd question: Why is the recipient being refused?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please ask only one question at a time, especially when they are on quite different topics.

Comment: you have to give access to the less secure app in the gmail's setting, the way you are doing it not secure I mean unencrypted and lots of security issues , that's why google apps by default refuse the connection, give access to less secure apps on your risk. this thread will help you https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en happy coding :-)

Comment: again the same mistake - `command=` expect **callback** - it means function name without `()`. No you use `command=send_otp(output, user_email)` so it first execute `send_otp` and when function returns value then it assigns result to `command=` and then it continue creating rest of widget and it runs `mainloop` which start displaying window.

Comment: if you need to assign function with arguments then you can use `lambda` - `command=lambda:send_otp(output, user_email)`

Comment: second problem can be because code was running `send_otp(output, user_email)` before  you put text in Entry so it use empty strings as `user_name` and `password`. `Entry` doesn't works like `input()`, it doesn't wait for your text, it only inform `mainloop` what widget you need in window - so when you run `email_in.get()` after `Entry()` then `entry` is still empty and you get() gives you empty string. You have to use get() in function assigned to button - `send_otp()`

Comment: BTW: next you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables `user_email`, `content`

Comment: *Before you decide to use this or publish it anywhere:* Don't reinvent the wheel. You're using a non-CS RNG (Mersenne twister) to create passwords. That's a no-go. There's plenty of packages out there that do the same thing quicker and more safely and that have a friendly API. If you insist on doing this yourself, use `os.urandom` or the `secrets` objects as a source for randomness.

Comment: @Coal_ Could you give an example? I'm still fairly new to this (this will be the most complex thing I've coded). Thanks!

Comment: [PyOTP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyotp) ([docs](https://pyotp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) seems pretty trustworthy.